# "ça ne lui fera pas de mal" vs "ça lui fera du bien": Which is stronger in meaning?

Tags: litote

> Je me persuade que **ça ne lui fera pas de mal** de manger moins et diététique !!

I assume this expression is considered litotes, ...

> Je me persuade que **ça lui fera du bien** de de manger moins et diététique !

...  so how does it compare to the straightforward affirmative construction?

I wonder which is stronger in meaning.

Comment: I think it depends how it is said. "Ca ne lui fera pas de mal" can be a way to say "ça lui fera du bien" but meaning we do not want to insist on why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"ça lui fera du bien"*

is just an objective way to speak. That will be good for him.

*"ça ne lui fera pas de mal"* has two meanings:

> Nothing to worry about. He can try it and that can eventually be good to him.

or

> *"Seriously, he needs to do something"* and for instance eating less and dietetic things (because he's too fat or other...)

Comment: « *(Je pense que) ça ne lui fera pas de mal de manger moins et diététique...* » Oh, j'y pense. :) Si je ne crois pas être bien placé pour lui donner un conseil sur un sujet plutôt délicat tel que celui-ci, est-ce que je pourrais tout aussi bien ***adoucir*** mes propos, en mettant simplement des points de suspension à la fin de la phrase ?

Answer (score 0):

To me there's not one stronger that the other. They have different nuances, but I wouldn't say one in stronger no matter what context it's in.

If you're helping you friend go through a depression (and you bring him a tea of something) "ça te fera du bien" feels stronger, whereas if you're angry at someone and want to teach him good manner, you might use the other one.